# Binding Json data to a table in mvc 4

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in an mvc 4 application..I want to bind a json data to a table in my application using jquery.I am able to convert a dataset (for which i get data from database) to json data using a method and get the json data.But i dont know how to bind it to a table using  jquery.Please tell me way to solve this problem..

**JSon data**:

My json data is something like this..

```
[{"Location":"Chennai","Duration":"15","Sno":"1",
 "Date of Birth":"\/Date(-2209051800000)\/","Dateofjoin":"\/Date(-2209048200000)\/"}]
```

**Jquery**:

```
$('#btnGoNew').click(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/Somecontroller/GetValue")'; 
        $.getJSON(url, { id: valz }, function (data) {
            //code to bind table                
        });
    });
```

**View**:

```
         <input type="button" class="MasterButton" id="btnGoNew"/>
            <table id="grd1">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>Location</th>
                   <th>Duration</th>
                   <th>Sno</th>
                   <th>Date of Birth</th>
                   <th>Dateofjoin</th>    
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td></td>
             </tr>
             </tbody>
           </table>
```

**Controller**:

```
   public JsonResult GetValue(string id)
    {
        JsonResult json = new JsonResult();
        DataSet ds = LoadDoctordetailsNew(id); 
       /*LoadDoctordetailsNew is method where i get data from database and convert
          to dataset.It returns a dataset*/
        string returnData = GetJson(ds.Tables[0]);
        json.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        json.Data = returnData;            
        return json;
    }

    public static string GetJson(DataTable dt)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer =
           new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows =
           new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
    }
```

Comment: your code helped me alot, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should parse the return json **string** to a json **object**:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Then, iterate through it and create your table. The complete solution is like the following:

```
$('#btnGoNew').click(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Content("~/DoctorDetail/GetValue")';
    $.getJSON(url, { id: valz }, function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        //code to bind table
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            var html = "<tr><td>" + item.Location + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + item.Duration + "</td>";
            // and html += other fields...
            $("#grd1 tr:last").after(html); 
            // the above line is like that because you use <tbody> 
            // in table definition.
        });                
    });

});
```

Comment: I don't think that you'll have problem to binding date like other fields. Do you have any problem? pls explain

Comment: ya for date fields i get undefined when binding..others all are binding perfectly..

Comment: remove white spaces from `Date of Birth` in your data definition to becomes like `DateOfBirth`. You also may have a problem to show the DateTime correctly. If so, define this function and use it to convert json date `function date(s) { return new Date(parseFloat(/Date\(([^)]+)\)/.exec(s)[1])); }`

Comment: where to use this function?

Comment: I cant Convert using this function.

Comment: This may be works too: `var thedate = Date(item.DateOfBirth);` then use `thedate` variable to bind to table cell.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33823/discussion-between-coder-and-aminsaghi)

Comment: its is like this 'Sat Jul 20 2013 14:43:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' but i need like this '
12/31/1899 12:00:00 PM'

Comment: maybe you can find an approach here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date`

Answer (score 0):

I Think You can't directly bind json into html table

You need to use any jquery plugins like

[Jqgrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

[DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

Or you can write your own plugins. Or you need to generate html table from the json.