# Return DataSet through Json object dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, dataset, circular-reference

I have the following code:

```
GenericManager gm = new GenericManager();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = gm.ExecuteQuery(gr.TableName, gr.ColumnName, gr.WhereClause);
return Json(ds, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In which `ExecuteQuery` is the method of the class `GenericManager` which will return dataset and that dataset is saved into the object `ds`.

I am implementing a functionality that will fetch data from different table everytime. It means that to populate the `DataSet` i am passing the name of the table of which data would be populated into the `DataSet`. So, I have to pass the dataset from Json everytime because i am not sure about the columns returned by the query.

If I try to return the dataset through Json then the following exception is thrown:
`A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'.`

So, i am looking for the way that will pass my `DataSet` to `Json`.

The following code that i have already tried is:

```
return Json(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Also,

```
 return Json(ds.Tables.AsQueryable(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**Please help to fix it, as i have to submit it by the end of the day**

Comment: You don't want to return the `DataSet`. You want to return the data. Although `DataSet`s have been XML serializable from the beginning, it was never recommended to do so because they are too platform specific.

Comment: yeah @PauloMorgado but why i am returning DataSet because i have to select data from different table every time, because i am incorporating the sql like functionality at the front end from which user can pick the table name and write there `where` query and then can make the statement `GO`

Comment: why don't you make a query to explicitly select what you want to return? Do you really want to return culture infos?

Comment: @PauloMorgado sorry but i dnt understand u, can u please explain a bit more what do you want to say

Comment: Something like `from t in ds.Tables select new { Table = t.TableName, Data = from r in t.Rows select new { ... } }`.

Comment: sorry but i am new to mvc, i want a proper explanation to understand this, you can post it as an answer i will not mind, but please help me understanding it fully.

Comment: And I know almost nothing about MVC. But from what I've looked up, `Controller.Json` serializes an object to JSON. What I'm recommending you to do is not to use the `DataSet` but to build an object that has only what you explicitly want. I would build the JSON myself instead of relying on such a generic serializer, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759253/binding-json-data-to-a-table-in-mvc-4) helped me a lot. For those who run into the same problem I suggest to check the solution.