# Angular 6/C#/MVC Dynamically return JsonResult from controller in form of Json Array of Array

Tags: c#, json, angular, async-await, dataformat

I am trying to export a number of datasets to Excel in an Angular 6 application. For that I am using XLSX and File-save as given in this ex:
https://medium.com/@madhavmahesh/exporting-an-excel-file-in-angular-927756ac9857

The problem is that the fields might keep changing time to time, so I need somthing dynamic (do not want to specify column names). For that I found a very good example:
[Binding Json data to a table in mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759253/binding-json-data-to-a-table-in-mvc-4)

However, I am not getting the data in the right format. I need something like array of array.
I am assuming the return type should be `async Task<JsonResult>` in that case but not sure how to make it work.
I am attaching two images - of the result I am getting [image: resultObtained]

and the intended result [image: ArrofArr]

Here is code from the sample cited. The stored proc call to GetMyData, uses SqlAdapter and there is no need to specify field names

```
 public JsonResult GetValue()
    {
        JsonResult json = new JsonResult();
        DataSet ds = GetMyData(); 
       /*LoadDoctordetailsNew is method where i get data from database and convert
          to dataset.It returns a dataset*/
        string returnData = GetJson(ds.Tables[0]);
        json.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        json.Data = returnData;            
        return json;
    }

    public static string GetJson(DataTable dt)
    {
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer =
           new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows =
           new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
    }

public static DataSet GetMyData()
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = Connection.GetConnection())
                {
                  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("dbo.MySQLStoredproc", connection);
                    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Please guide!

P.S.

This technique is **using Dapper**. It returns data as desired (Array of Array) format, but in the Object we have to specify column names which will be hard coding and *therefore, I can't use*

```
public static IEnumerable<Object> GetMyData()
        {

            var strQuery = @"[dbo].[Myproc]";        
            IEnumerable< Object > items = new List<Object>(0);
            var p = new DynamicParameters();

            using (SqlConnection con = Connection.GetConnection())
            {
                items = con.Query<Object>(strQuery, param: p, commandTimeout: 120, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }
            return items;
        }
```

Call from MVC Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> SelectMyData()
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => Request.GetMyData());

    var retData = await task;
    return new JsonResult
    {
        ContentType = "application/json",
        Data = retData,
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
        MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue
    };
}
```

Comment: I can't distinguish between the result you are getting and your intended results, they're the same, no?

Comment: no, they are not. the intended result is hardcoded in the Angular typescript file and as given the the exporting an excel file example. I am returning the same results in form of dataset using ex: 'Binding Json data to a table in mvc 4'. The intended result successfully creates excel file but not the actual result

Comment: Looks like you're sending back a string rather than the object. Are you parsing it into JSON yourself? .NET will do that for you, just return the array as is.

Comment: Please show the code that you did so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` instead of `string`. You don't need to `Serialize` the data it will be take care by `JsonResult`

```
public JsonResult GetValue()
{
    JsonResult json = new JsonResult();
    DataSet ds = GetMyData(); 
   /*LoadDoctordetailsNew is method where i get data from database and convert
      to dataset.It returns a dataset*/
    json.Data = GetJson(ds.Tables[0]);
    json.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    return json;
}

public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetJson(DataTable dt)
{
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows =
       new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You made my day